# Named color do not work prior to iOS 11.0

Tags: swift, uicolor, xcode9.2

I have created some custom named colors for using in my project earlier it was working fine. When i install Xcode 9.2 it is showing me "Named color do not work prior to iOS 11.0". (My phone version is 11.1.1.)

[image]

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Your project target must be set to at least iOS 11

Comment: @zisoft Thanks it solve problem.

Comment: There is a workaround here: https://medium.com/@letatas/how-to-use-color-assets-prior-to-ios-11-206d0cbf516f

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Setting project target to 11 solved issue

Comment: the easiest but not the smartest answer

Comment: @Lucas do you have any better solution?

Comment: Unable to solve this way on Xcode 11.3 and iOS 13.3

Answer (score -1):

Change the color from e.g. "backgroundColor" to a custom color (see "Other...") or to a color from the iPhoneSDK.

[image]

Comment: It's not a solution, named color is a custom color set in asset folder.